# Attempting to Update multiple fields in single row but instead creating duplicate rows

Tags: sqlite

**Edit :** [Salesforce Marketing Cloud uses a set of SQL Server](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5).

I'm using a SQL query in Salesforce Marketing Cloud which means I'm limited to doing a 'Select' statement as an overwrite to the table [Distribution]. I am attempting to perform the following actions:

```
select * from [Subscribers] A
inner join [Master Table] B on A.MemberID = B.MemberID
```

This part works as expected.

Next I have two fields, Reward1 and Reward2, that each corresponds to a specific RewardCode in [Offers]. So what I'm trying to do (I think) should be a left join join with [Subscribers] and [Offers] on MemberID where RewardCode = 111111 and a left join with [Subscribers] and [Offers] where RewardCode = 222222. However this is where I seem to be creating duplicate records.

An example of the schema could look like this:

**master member table**

```
memberID | email | fname | lname
1111 | 1111@email.com | One | Name
2222 | 2222@email.com | Two | Name
3333 | 3333@email.com | Three | Name
4444 | 4444@email.com | Four | Name
```

**subscribers**

```
memberID | status | subscriberkey
1111 | active | 1111@email.com
2222 | active | 2222@email.com
3333 | active | 3333@email.com
4444 | active | 4444@email.com
```

**master reward table**

```
memberID | rewardcode
1111 | 111111
1111 | 111111
1111 | 111111
2222 | 111111
2222 | 222222
2222 | 222222
3333 | 222222
3333 | 111111
4444 | 222222
4444 | 333333
4444 | 222222
```

And ideally the resulting table would resemble this:

```
[distribution]
subscriberkey | memberId | status| reward1 | reward2
1111@email.com| 1111 | active | TRUE | FALSE
2222@email.com| 2222 | active TRUE | TRUE
3333@email.com| 3333 | active TRUE | TRUE
4444@email.com| 4444 | active FALSE | TRUE
```

Full query:

```
SELECT A.SubscriberKey AS SubscriberKey, A.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress,
A.MemberID AS MemberId, A.Status AS Status,
A.Decile AS Decile, A.Segment AS Segment, M.Firstname AS FirstName,
M.LastName AS LastName, M.Points AS PointsAvailable,
M.Experience AS Experience,
    CASE
        WHEN M.[Preferred Delivery Method for Offers] = 2 THEN 'SMS'
        ELSE 'Email'
    END AS PreferredDeliveryOffers,
    CASE
        WHEN M.[Preferred Delivery Method for Non-Offers] = 2 THEN 'SMS'
        ELSE 'Email'
    END AS PreferredDeliveryNonOffers,
    CASE
        WHEN R.MemberRewardBarcode IS NOT NULL AND
        R.[Member ID] = M.MemberId AND
        R.MemberRewardBarcode = 1111111 THEN 'Reward15'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Reward15,
    CASE
        WHEN B.MemberRewardBarcode IS NOT NULL AND
        B.[Member ID] = M.MemberId AND
        B.MemberRewardBarcode = 2222222 THEN 'RewardBDay'
        ELSE ''
    END AS RewardBDay
FROM Subscribers A
INNER JOIN [Master Member Table] M
    ON A.MemberID = M.MemberId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT MemberRewardBarcode, [Member ID]
    FROM [master rewards table] R
    WHERE R.MemberRewardBarcode = 1111111 AND
    R.CancelTimestamp IS NULL AND
    R.ExpireTimestamp IS NULL AND
    R.RedeemTimestamp IS NULL
  ) R ON A.MemberID = R.[Member ID]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT MemberRewardBarcode, [Member ID]
    FROM [master rewards table] R
    WHERE R.MemberRewardBarcode = 2222222 AND
    R.CancelTimestamp IS NULL AND
    R.ExpireTimestamp IS NULL AND
    R.RedeemTimestamp IS NULL
    GROUP BY MemberRewardBarcode, [Member ID]
  ) B ON A.MemberID = R.[Member ID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adress this using *conditional aggregation* :

```
SELECT 
    s.subscriberkey,
    s.memberID,
    s.status,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r.rewardcode = 111111 THEN 1 END) reward1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN r.rewardcode = 222222 THEN 1 END) reward2
FROM 
    subscribers s
    LEFT JOIN reward r ON r.memberID = s.memberID
GROUP BY 
    s.subscriberkey,
    s.memberID,
    s.status
```

This query uses very common SQL syntax (aggregation and `CASE`), which, as far as I can see in the documentation you provided, should be supported on Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

This **[SQLServer 2017 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3301dc4a44c31771eca12d144b8a105d)** returns :

```
 subscriberkey  | memberID | status | reward1 | reward2
 :------------- | -------: | :----- | ------: | ------:
 1111@email.com |     1111 | active |       1 |    null
 2222@email.com |     2222 | active |       1 |       1
 3333@email.com |     3333 | active |       1 |       1
 4444@email.com |     4444 | active |    null |    null
```